# How can i get the color value if i duplicate the input field in bootstrap colorpicker. can someone help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem to get the color value on input field when i duplicate it. How can i get the color value if i duplicate the input field in bootstrap colorpicker. can someone help me?

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="cp4">Change background color</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="cp4">Change background color</a>
      <script>
          $(function () {
              $('#cp4').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function (e) {
                  $('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = e.color.toString('rgba');
              });
          });
      </script>
```

Please check the original code: https://itsjavi.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `id` is meant to be unique..use `class` for this

Comment: You cannot have the same `id` on multiple elements, it *must* be unique. If you want to group elements use a class.

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it now, but you can try this

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default cp4">Change background color</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default cp4">Change background color</a>

$(function() {
  $('.cp4').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function() {
    var value = $(this).colorpicker('getValue');
    // do what you want
  });
});
```

Comment: you need to ad dthe cp4 to the existing class definititions - you cannot specifiy two sets of classes for the one element

Answer (score 0):

as comment discuss - you must have a unique id -so you could apply a class to each button - or wrap both in a parent with the id and call the function on the clik of the .btn class within the div.

```
<div id="cp4">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" >Change background color</a>

  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Change background color</a>
</div

//js
      <script>
          $(function () {
              $('#cp4 .btn').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function (e) {
                  $('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = e.color.toString('rgba');
              });
          });
      </script>
```

Comment: I think you have to remove the `id` attribute in the second `a` tag because otherwise it's duplicated

Comment: thanks @UfguFugullu - amended - the dangers of copy and paste